# Prepare sequences of rows using pandas

Tags: pandas

I have this dataset of transactions:

```
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| name | amount | feat1 | feat2 |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| dave | 24     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| john | 55     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| dave | 56     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| dave | 94     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| dave | 10     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| john | 3      | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| dave | 7      | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| john | 77     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| john | 88     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| dave | 34     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| john | 84     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| john | 22     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
```

I want to create sequences from that will look like:

`window_size` past transactions --> next transaction, but to do it per customer. Meanining, for `window_size = 4` I want the output to look something like:

```
source: 

+------+--------+-------+-------+
| name | amount | feat1 | feat2 |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| dave | 24     | -     | -     |                  next:
+------+--------+-------+-------+               
| dave | 56     | -     | -     |      +------+--------+-------+-------+
+------+--------+-------+-------+      | dave | 7      | -     | -     |
| dave | 94     | -     | -     |      +------+--------+-------+-------+
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| dave | 10     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+

source:                                       

+------+--------+-------+-------+
| name | amount | feat1 | feat2 |
+------+--------+-------+-------+               next:
| dave | 56     | -     | -     |            
+------+--------+-------+-------+     +------+--------+-------+-------+
| dave | 94     | -     | -     |     | dave | 34     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+     +------+--------+-------+-------+
| dave | 10     | -     | -     |   
+------+--------+-------+-------+   
| dave | 7      | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+


source:
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| name | amount | feat1 | feat2 |
+------+--------+-------+-------+                 next:
| john | 55     | -     | -     |                
+------+--------+-------+-------+      +------+--------+-------+-------+            
| john | 3      | -     | -     |      | john | 84     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+      +------+--------+-------+-------+
| john | 77     | -     | -     |      
+------+--------+-------+-------+      
| john | 88     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+

 source:
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| name | amount | feat1 | feat2 |
+------+--------+-------+-------+                  next:
| john | 3      | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+        +------+--------+-------+-------+
| john | 77     | -     | -     |        | john | 22     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+        +------+--------+-------+-------+
| john | 88     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| john | 84     | -     | -     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
```

and the same for the other user 'john', and in general for each user.
I want my output to be two python variables: `sequences` and `targets`
`sequences` will be of shape `(window_size, num_features)` and `tragets` will be of shape `(1, num_features)`

Comment: What operation would you like to do over the past transactions? The result should be the `mean` value,  the `min` or something different?

Comment: just stack them together and to keep it as a dataframe

Comment: But how do you get the `target` from the past transactions?

Comment: just the next transaction, I've edited my question to project that

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate


def extract_window_and_target(df, i, window_size):
    # get the data with same user and with index bigger than i
    user_name = df.iloc[i, :][0]
    user_events_from_i = df.iloc[i:, :].loc[df["name"] == user_name, :]
    # extract window and target
    X = user_events_from_i.iloc[:window_size, :].reset_index(drop=True)
    y = user_events_from_i.iloc[window_size:window_size + 1, :].reset_index(drop=True)
    has_empty_target = True if len(y) == 0 else False
    return X, y, has_empty_target


columns = ["name", "amount"]
data = [["dave", "24"],
        ["john", "55"],
        ["dave", "56"],
        ["dave", "94"],
        ["dave", "10"],
        ["john", "3"],
        ["dave", "7"],
        ["john", "77"],
        ["john", "88"],
        ["dave", "34"],
        ["john", "84"],
        ["john", "22"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

window_size = 4
for i in range(len(df)):
    X, y, has_empty_target = extract_window_and_target(df, i, window_size)
    if not has_empty_target:
        print("window (training data) :")
        print(tabulate(X, headers=X.columns, tablefmt="psql"))
        print("target:")
        print(tabulate(y, headers=y.columns, tablefmt="psql"))
```

Output:

```
window 0 (training data) :
+----+--------+----------+
|    | name   |   amount |
|----+--------+----------|
|  0 | dave   |       24 |
|  1 | dave   |       56 |
|  2 | dave   |       94 |
|  3 | dave   |       10 |
+----+--------+----------+
target 0:
+----+--------+----------+
|    | name   |   amount |
|----+--------+----------|
|  0 | dave   |        7 |
+----+--------+----------+
window 1 (training data) :
+----+--------+----------+
|    | name   |   amount |
|----+--------+----------|
|  0 | john   |       55 |
|  1 | john   |        3 |
|  2 | john   |       77 |
|  3 | john   |       88 |
+----+--------+----------+
target 1:
+----+--------+----------+
|    | name   |   amount |
|----+--------+----------|
|  0 | john   |       84 |
+----+--------+----------+
window 2 (training data) :
+----+--------+----------+
|    | name   |   amount |
|----+--------+----------|
|  0 | dave   |       56 |
|  1 | dave   |       94 |
|  2 | dave   |       10 |
|  3 | dave   |        7 |
+----+--------+----------+
target 2:
+----+--------+----------+
|    | name   |   amount |
|----+--------+----------|
|  0 | dave   |       34 |
+----+--------+----------+
window 5 (training data) :
+----+--------+----------+
|    | name   |   amount |
|----+--------+----------|
|  0 | john   |        3 |
|  1 | john   |       77 |
|  2 | john   |       88 |
|  3 | john   |       84 |
+----+--------+----------+
target 5:
+----+--------+----------+
|    | name   |   amount |
|----+--------+----------|
|  0 | john   |       22 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

It will work also if you have multiple features in the Dataframe.
(..however it is not the optimal solution for speed)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. After i was conviced it does work, I am wondering what it the best solution in terms of speed. Maybe using pandas' ```groupby``` and ```rolling``` functions?

Comment: yes, rolling and applying `extract_window_and_target ` will give a boost of speed because you can avoid to filter the whole dataset every iteration. however if you accept the fact of losing the chronological order of the transaction, the solution of Ralobrusto should be faster ( he filters only once for each name ).

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your dataframe is called `df`, you can try the following code:

```
window_size = 4
my_transactions = {}

for name in df['name'].unique():
    _user_transactions = df[df['name'] == name]

    my_transactions[name] = [
        {
            'past': _user_transactions.iloc[i:i+window_size],
            'target': _user_transactions.iloc[i+window_size]
        }
        for i in range(len(_user_transactions) - window_size)
    ]
```

This will return a `dictionary` with keys equal to the user names.

For each user there will be a list of dictionaries, each one with the keys `past` and `target`, containing the respective DataFrames. See example below

```
for name in my_transactions:
    print('User:', name)
    for transaction in my_transactions[name]:
        print('Past transactions:')
        print(transaction['past'])
        print('Target transaction:')
        print(transaction['target'])
        print()
    print()
```

For user `dave` the output is:

```
User: dave
Past transactions:
   name  amount
0  dave      24
2  dave      56
3  dave      94
4  dave      10
Target transaction:
name      dave
amount       7
Name: 6, dtype: object

Past transactions:
   name  amount
2  dave      56
3  dave      94
4  dave      10
6  dave       7
Target transaction:
name      dave
amount      34
Name: 9, dtype: object
```

And for `john`

```
User: john
Past transactions:
   name  amount
1  john      55
5  john       3
7  john      77
8  john      88
Target transaction:
name      john
amount      84
Name: 10, dtype: object

Past transactions:
    name  amount
5   john       3
7   john      77
8   john      88
10  john      84
Target transaction:
name      john
amount      22
Name: 11, dtype: object
```

Let us know if you have any further issues.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it does work. I was wondering if it scales for datasets with millions of records. Do you think it can be implemented with more efficent way? like using pandas' ```groupby``` and ```rolling```?